# API to push data to HealthKit

Tags: ios, api, embedded, healthkit, google-fit

My ultimate goal: I want to automatically log my weight to healthkit on my phone every time I step on the scale.

Secondary goal: I don't want to spend much money, but I do want to learn.  I'm a computer engineer and enjoy building hardware, but I don't just want to buy an off-the-shelf smart scale and install their app.  Part of this comes down to data security: I don't like my information (especially health information) being in somebody else's hands.

Tertiary goal: I don't want to need an apple developer account (e.g., to roll my own on-phone app or something) but if I have to compromise here I will.

I want this to be as painless a process as possible - I've seen solutions that involve setting up a shortcut to ask for your current weight, etc, and I don't love that: less user interaction is better.

I'm usually wearing my apple watch when I weight myself, but might forget my phone (it's often right after a workout before I shower), if that helps.

I've seen a lot of questions on here talking about querying data, and I don't care about that: I'll use the phone to look at historical data, but I want to enter it automatically/painlessly so I have some data to look at.

For instance: I could set up an NFC sticker to open a shortcut, and maybe the process of scanning the sticker holds my phone in a specific place to read a QR code output by the scale? I honestly don't know if scanning a QR is possible in a shortcut, but this is just an example.  The downside here is that I would need my phone on me.

The most promising solution from what I can tell is to build my scale to send the weight to google fit's API, and then install the google fit app on my phone to sync automatically.  The downside is exposing my info to another service (google fit) rather than just keeping it in HealthKit, which I'd prefer.

Is there an auto-magic URL format that could trigger an iOS behavior to enter the data?

Is there an API through iCloud to just submit the data and not query it?

Is there a bluetooth option to talk to my watch and sync data there?

I see a lot of questions for querying/reading HealthKit data, but very little on submitting/saving it - so I'm not sure what's possible.

Suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Way too broad a question for SO in my opinion, and you will get more readers if you omit the irellevant personal information and get to the point in _much less_ text.  For example describe the system you need to build and it's requirements; omit the personal reasons for those decisions - no one needs to know your privacy concerns, and certainly not your when you choose to weigh yourself (or even what you wish to weigh for that matter).  It is also in part a hardware question, which generally  is off-topic here.

Comment: You need a developer account. You can find a library which does bluetooth comms to scales on GitHub. it probably needs conversion to iOS. You can then write an iOS app which pairs with your scale when close and reads weight and stores it in HealthKit via the api.

Comment: @Clifford Fair points on all counts.  I think I delved too far into it since I've had responses like "Oh, just do this..." and wanted to clarify some of my design goals.

The 2 second version of this question is "What options are there for programmatically getting data IN to healthkit - preferably without external apps or a developer account?"

In your opinion, would that be more on-topic?